# How to do HTTPS GET request AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

This is the method I use to do HTTP GET request. How can I change it to use HTTPS?

AS_NET_BASE_URL = http://www.myapp.com

Is it just as simple as replacing the http://  with https://   ?

Thank you in advance

```
+(void)startGETRequestAtUrlRoute:(NSString *)route withParameters:(NSString *)slashSeparatedParams completion:(void (^)(BOOL, id))completion{

    //If internet is rachable, start request
    if ([self isInternetReachable]) {

        //Where request is going
        AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:AS_NET_BASE_URL]];

        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", AS_NET_BASE_URL, route, slashSeparatedParams];

        //Tell operation to expect JSON
        [httpClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [httpClient setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

        //Start spinner
        [self startNetworkIndicator];

        //Set up actual GET request
        [httpClient getPath:path
                 parameters:nil
                    success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                        //Stop spinning
                        [self stopNetworkIndicator];

                        //Make the response JSON valid
                        if (responseObject) {
                            completion(YES, responseObject);
                        }
                    }

                    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                        [self stopNetworkIndicator];

                        completion(NO, NULL);
                        //Error
                        NSLog(@"%@", error);

                    }
         ];

        //No internet connection
    }else{
        completion(NO, NULL);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

HTTP/HTTPS is determined by the scheme of the URL, which in your case is specified in `AS_NET_BASE_URL`.